# Is there a guide to converting a document-based Cocoa application to non-document-based and/or vice versa?

Tags: cocoa

If not, this is about as good a place as any to write one. I'm facing the possibility of just such a conversion in a project and wondered if anyone has been down the road or if the process is documented somewhere.

Comment: Document and non-document based applications are very different, architecturally. Which way are you trying to go?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this post](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DocumentBasedAppWithOneWindowForAllDocuments) on CocoaDev.com is the best so far…